# Unable to get social buttons to align using span/div

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I've tried messing with the css and html code and I can't seem to get the social icons to align at all. I want to align Facebook's and Twitter's share buttons next to each other with partial padding between them both.

Here is what it currently looks like:
[image]

Here is the code:

```html
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="heading display-3 mb-4"><span style="-webkit-text-stroke: 2px black;"></span>Saint Louis Events</div>
                <p class="headingParagraph">Don't know who we are? What we do? There's no doubt that we are the ultimate underdogs, but usually the smallest bark the loudest and we're here to stay.
                    <br><b>We will prevail. We will impress. We are here for you.</b>
                </p>
                <div class="svg-wrapper">
                    <svg height="40" width="180" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                      <rect class="shape" height="40" width="180" />
                    </svg>
                      <div class="text">ABOUT US</div>
                </div>
                <span>
                    <div class="fb-share-button" data-href="http://www.eventsinstlouis.com/" data-layout="button_count" data-size="small" data-mobile-iframe="true"><a target="_blank" href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.eventsinstlouis.com%2F&amp;src=sdkpreparse" class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore">Share</a></div>
                </span>
                <span>
                    <a href="https://twitter.com/share?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw" class="twitter-share-button" data-url="http://www.eventsinstlouis.com/" data-hashtags="stlouisevents" data-show-count="false">Tweet</a><script async src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
                </span>
            </div>
```

Comment: use `vertical-align:top`

Comment: Thanks for the help! I found where it's defined as vertical-align: bottom in the Facebook social button css. How would I be able to overwrite this? [Click here for image](https://i.imgur.com/EbbNBcD.png)

Comment: play with the vertical-align of the twitter, try to make this one bottom also

Comment: Got it to work using `.fb_iframe_widget span {
    vertical-align: top!important;
}` - Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to find where Facebook is predefining the vertical-align: bottom attribute but I don't see a class that I can define to overwrite it, how would I be able to overwrite this?
[image]

Comment: Got it working! Used this piece: `.fb_iframe_widget span {
    vertical-align: top!important;
}`.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.facebook , .twitter
{
float:left;
margin-right:20px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<span class="facebook">facebook</span><span class="twitter">tweet</span>
</body>
</html>
```